# Syntax Error in INSERT INTO statement, no other details given

Tags: ms-access, insert, oledb

The SQL generated my code looks like this -

```
INSERT INTO [Item] (
  Vendor_num
, item
, [Desc]
, Pack
, item_size
, unit_of_sale
, allowance
, points
, Promo
, WS_Cost
, WS_Unit_cost
, Retailer_Price
, Retail
, Cust_Use
, Show_Price
, GP
, Min
, Max
, Book_Number
, Del1_date
, Del2_date
, Del3_date
, Del4_date
, Del5_date
, Del6_date
, Del7_date
, Del8_date
, Del9_date
, Del10_date
, Del11_date
, Del12_date
, Del13_date
, Del14_date
, Del15_date
, warehouse
, Purchase_Group
, GPM
, Material_Number
, PM
) VALUES (
  '11'
, '300681'
, 'item description'
, '60'
, 'BOX'
, 'BOX'
, '3'
, '20'
, 'Y'
, '0'
, null
, '0'
, null
, '03652'
, null
, null
, null
, null
, '832'
, '6/2/2014 12:00:00 AM'
, '6/30/2014 12:00:00 AM'
, '7/28/2014 12:00:00 AM'
, '8/18/2014 12:00:00 AM'
, null
, null
, null
, null
, null
, null
, null
, null
, null
, null
, null
, '1'
, null
, null
, null
, null
)
```

(forgive all those `null` values, they're frequently not null in these inserts, so the statement needs to be flexible enough when they're not)

I'm  getting a generic error --

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement.
```

The statement works fine when copied directly into a new query in Access, but when firing through .NET and OLE DB, it fails miserably.

Any ideas?

Comment: I know pretty much nothing about Access, but I'd try to use `[Min]` and `[Max]` instead of using them unquoted.

Comment: The date delimiter is #, not ', so #6/2/2014 12:00:00 AM#

Comment: While I agree with @JoachimIsaksson that [] would solve the problem, I recommend that you start prefixing field / column names with the table name, or better, the table alias. This will prevent any reserved word errors, be more readable, and upscale nicely to other databases.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson - please submit your comment as an answer, it has worked fantastically. I'm quite surprised Access itself didn't throw a fit about that, which is why I didn't even think to try it. =)

Comment: @Remou I really wish Access was more consistent about this. I agree that `#` is the thing to use but I just tested and the single quotes work just fine as well.

Comment: @Brad That is new, and yes, very annoying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Min` and `Max` are [reserved words in Access](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/access-help/access-2007-reserved-words-and-symbols-HA010030643.aspx), and should be quoted if you use them as field names or you may encounter errors;

> If a reserved word is already in use, you can avoid error messages by surrounding each occurrence of the word with brackets ([ ]). However, the best solution is to change the name to a nonreserved word.

In other words, used as field names, they should be quoted as `[Min]` and `[Max]`.